# Updating Media Item Stream on Item:Saved Event

Tags: media-library, events

I had implemented a `item:saved` event handler that updates the `MediaStream` of a `MediaItem`. The code is roughly like this:

```
  public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
        SitecoreEventArgs evtArgs = args as SitecoreEventArgs;
        if(evtArgs == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            Item item = Event.ExtractParameter<Item>(evtArgs, 0);
            if ((item.Database != null)
                && item.Database.Name.ToLower().Equals("master")
                && item.Paths.IsMediaItem)
            {
                Media media = MediaManager.GetMedia(item);
                if (media != null)
                {
                    MediaStream mediaStream = media.GetStream();
                    if (StreamProcessor.SupportedExtensions.Contains(media.Extension)
                        && (mediaStream != null))
                    {
                        Log.Info(string.Format("Begin media stream processing for {0} ({1}, {2})",
                                               item.Name,
                                               item.ID,
                                               item.Paths.FullPath
                                               )
                                 , this);

                        using (EventDisabler evtDisabler = new EventDisabler())
                        {
                            Stream oriStream = mediaStream.Stream;
                            MemoryStream procStream = oriStream.Copy(false);
                            Stream _newStream = StreamProcessor.DoSomething(procStream);
                            MediaStream newStream = new MediaStream(_newStream, media.Extension, item);
                            media.SetStream(newStream);
                        }

                        Log.Info(string.Format("End media stream processing for {0} ({1}, {2})",
                                               item.Name,
                                               item.ID,
                                               item.Paths.FullPath
                                               )
                                 , this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Fail safe, should not fails the entire Content Editor or Codes
            Log.Error("Unable to process media stream due to general error.", ex, this);
        }
  }
```

My problem is:

- It seems does not play nicely with Sitecore event in overall (it called numerous times including on lock changes, last updates, etc). How should i detect that the changes is only the `MediaStream`?
  Currently i can probe lock changes by checking the `ItemChanges` from `SitecoreEventArgs.Parameters`. However the item changes seems did not say anything for `MediaStream` changes.

  ```
  private bool _IsLockChange(SitecoreEventArgs evtArgs)
  {
      IEnumerable<object> parameters = evtArgs.Parameters;
      object itemChangesObj = parameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x is ItemChanges);

      if (itemChangesObj != null)
      {
          ItemChanges itemChanges = (ItemChanges)itemChangesObj;
          if (itemChanges.FieldChanges.Contains(FieldIDs.Lock))
          {
              //Skip
              return true;
          }
      }

      return false;
  }
  ```

  When the `SetStream` is called several times (due lock changes for instance), the media attached into the item will be lost on the backend UI.
  It also causes a custom data provider is not firing properly.
- Is it possible the `EventDisabler` is the cause of the issue above?
  Though I believe it should not, the custom data provider developer points to it.
- Is it safe to update MediaStream in item:saved event?
  Looking at the issue I found above, it is apparent that I need to find an alternative.
- What is the alternative to modify `MediaStream` of a `MediaItem` to ensure that every single file is processed through my custom method?
  I'm checking `UiUpload` processor to no luck as `HttpFileCollection` only has read-only streams.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**

Currently, the media has already been saved to the item and when you are modifying the Media Stream, the updated media stream is not being updated on the item.

**Solution**

You should use the `item:saving` event instead. This event will fire once the user clicks save. So, you will update the media stream during this event.

If you are using the `EventDisabler`, you should note that it will not trigger the other events. So, it may be the case that the events `item:saved` will not trigger.

Comment: i thought `EventDisabler` will only disable event that incurred within the `EventDisabler` scope and the next stack still accessible. also, supposedly i used the `item:saving`, how to retrieve the new `MediaStream`?

Comment: When you use the event `item:saving`, it will already has the updated Media stream. you just need to update it for base on your requirement

Comment: ok, i'll try. so, drop the `EventDisabler` also? last time i tried it become endless stackoverflow (obviously).